# Find the maximum of the function in R

Tags: r, function, survival-analysis, maximize

I have the following function.

[image]

Let F(.) is the cumulative distribution function of the `gamma` distribution with `shape = 1` and `rate =1`.  The denominator is the survival function `S(X) = 1 - F(X)`. The `g(x)` is the mean residual life function.

I wrote the following function in r.

```
x = 5
denominator = 1 -pgamma(x, 1, 1)
numerator = function(t) (1 - pgamma(t, 1, 1))

intnum  = integrate(numerator , x, Inf)

frac = intnum$value/denominator
frac
```

How can I find the maximum of the function `g(x)` for all possible values of `X >= 0`? Am I able to do this in `r`? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I'm think the results you are getting are due to numerical instability rather than being an interesting or useful result. With a shape of 1, pgamma is just exponential, so I think there should be no unique maximum. Notice that the g(x) that is plotted says exactly 1.0 until x > 30 and then briefly jiggles around 1 before dropping to effectively zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before start, I defined the function you made

```
surviveFunction<-function(x){
  denominator = 1 -pgamma(x, 1, 1)
  numerator = function(t) (1 - pgamma(t, 1, 1))

  # I used sapply to get even vector x
  intnum  = sapply(x,function(x){integrate(numerator , x, Inf)$value})
  
  frac = intnum/denominator
  return(frac)
}
```

Then let's fit our function to function called 'curve' it will draw the plot with continuous data.

The result is shown below:

```
df = curve(surviveFunction, from=0, to=45)
plot(df, type='l')
```

[image]
And adjust the `xlim` to find the maximum value

```
df = curve(surviveFunction, from=0, to=45,xlim = c(30,40))
plot(df, type='l')
```

[image]

And now we can guess the global maximum is located in near `35`

I suggest two options to find the global maximum.

First using the `df` data to find maximum:

```
> max(df$y,na.rm = TRUE)
 1.054248 #maximum value

> df$x[which(df$y==(max(df$y,na.rm = TRUE)))]
 35.55 #maximum value of x
```

Second using the  `optimize`:

```
> optimize(surviveFunction, interval=c(34, 36), maximum=TRUE)

$maximum
[1] 35.48536

$objective
[1] 1.085282
```

But the `optimize` function finds the not the global maximum value i think.

If you see below

```
optimize(surviveFunction, interval=c(0, 36), maximum=TRUE)

$maximum
[1] 11.11381

$objective
[1] 0.9999887
```

Above result is not the global maximum I guess it is local maximum.

So, I suggest you using first solution.