# A tidy way to find the max of a function in an interval: pipes, sequences and subsetting

Tags: r, magrittr

I'm looking for an idiomatic (pipe-based) way to find the minimum/maximum of a given function in an interval. Let's say I have an arbitrary function, such as

```
f<-function(x){return(x^2-10*x)}
```

I'm looking for its minimum value in [xmin:xmax]. Of course with the above example, this is trivial but obviously a real-life application would use a much more complex f, probably with parameters, etc, etc.

The "plain" R way would be, for instance (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56639782/find-the-maximum-of-the-function-in-r))

```
xmin <- 0
xmax <- 10

df<-curve(f,xmin,xmax)
df$x[which(df$y==(min(df$y,na.rm = TRUE)))]
```

or

```
optimize(f, interval=c(xmin,xmax), maximum=F)$min
```

For the sake of curiosity (and understanding plumbing), let's assume I want a "tidy" equivalent of the first solution, using pipes. I managed to construct

```
seq(xmin,xmax,length.out = 100) %>% f %>% which.min()
```

which gives me the index of the lowest value. Of course I can now do

```
idx <- seq(xmin,xmax,length.out = 100) %>% f %>% which.min()
seq(xmin,xmax,length.out = 100)[idx]
```

but surely there is a more idiomatic way to pipe the result of my construction and get the X-value without intermediate variables (xmin, xmax and idx) ?

(yes, I *know* that this gives me only an approximate value, to the nearest step in my sequence, and yes this is a somewhat construed example - I'm trying to improve my understanding of pipes)

Comment: `seq(xmin,xmax,length.out = 100) %>% f %>% min` ?

Comment: Not quite, this gives the lowest value (y) of the function but not the x coordinate of the min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
xmin <- 0
xmax <- 10

f<-function(x){
  return(x^2-10*x)
}

curve(f,xmin,xmax) %>% 
as_tibble() %>%
filter(y == min(y)) %>%
pull(x)
```

or:

```
curve(f,xmin,xmax) %>% 
  {.$x[which.min(.$y)]}
```

Comment: Ah, yes. Of course, it did not occur to me to make it a tibble first. Thanks. For a bonus point - is there a way to avoid the tibble stage, i.e. pass the result of the pipeline to the subsetting operator ? Something like ... %>% .[] , maybe ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.