# Calculate y value for distribution fitting functions R

Tags: r, distribution, curve

I am plotting curves for different distribution functions and I need to know the highest y-value for each curve. Later I will plot only the one curve, which is selected as the best fitting.

This is the function (it is a bit hard-coded, I am working on it):

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(fitdistrplus)
library(evd)
library(gamlss)
        
        
fdistr <- function(d) {
  
  #  Uncomment to try  run line by line
  # d <- data_to_plot
  
  TLT <- d$TLT
  if (sum(TLT<=0)) {TLT[TLT<=0] <- 0.001} # removing value < 0 for log clculation
  gev <- fgev(TLT, std.err=FALSE)
  distr <- c('norm', 'lnorm', 'weibull', 'gamma')
  fit <- lapply(X=distr, FUN=fitdist, data=TLT)
  fit[[5]] <- gev
  distr[5] <- 'gev'
  names(fit) <- distr
  Loglike <- sapply(X=fit, FUN=logLik)
  Loglike_Best <- which(Loglike == max(Loglike))
  
  #  Uncomment to try  run line by line
  # max <- which.max(density(d$TLT)$y)
  # max_density <- stats::density(d$TLT)$y[max]
  # max_y <- max_density
  
  x_data <- max(d$TLT)
  
  hist(TLT, prob=TRUE, breaks= x_data,
       main=paste(d$DLT_Code[1], 
                  '- best :',
                  names(Loglike[Loglike_Best])),
       sub = 'Total Lead Times',
       col='lightgrey',
       border='white'
       # ylim=  c(0,max_y)
  )
  
  lines(density(TLT),
        col='darkgrey',
        lty=2,
        lwd=2)
  
  grid(nx = NA, ny = NULL, col = "gray", lty = "dotted",
       lwd = .5, equilogs = TRUE)
  
  curve(dnorm(x, 
              mean=fit[['norm']]$estimate[1], 
              sd=fit[['norm']]$estimate[2]), 
        add=TRUE, col='blue', lwd=2)
  
  curve(dlnorm(x, 
               meanlog=fit[['lnorm']]$estimate[1], 
               sdlog=fit[['lnorm']]$estimate[2]), 
        add=TRUE, col='darkgreen', lwd=2)
  
  curve(dweibull(x, 
                 shape=fit[['weibull']]$estimate[1], 
                 scale=fit[['weibull']]$estimate[2]), 
        add=TRUE, col='purple', lwd=2)
  
  curve(dgamma(x, 
               shape=fit[['gamma']]$estimate[1], 
               rate=fit[['gamma']]$estimate[2]), 
        add=TRUE, col='Gold', lwd=2)
  
  
  curve(dgev(x, 
             loc=fit[['gev']]$estimate[1],
             scale=fit[['gev']]$estimate[2], 
             shape=fit[['gev']]$estimate[3]), 
        add=TRUE, col='red', lwd=2)
  
  
  legend_loglik <- paste(c('Norm', 'LogNorm', 'Weibull', 'Gamma','GEV'), c(':'),
                         round(Loglike, digits=2))
  
  legend("topright", legend=legend_loglik, 
         col=c('blue', 'darkgreen', 'purple', 'gold', 'red'),
         lty=1, lwd=2,
         bty='o', bg='white', box.lty=2, box.lwd = 1, box.col='white')  
  
  return(data.frame(DLT_Code = d$DLT_Code[1],
                    n = length(d$TLT),
                    Best = names(Loglike[Loglike_Best]),
                    lnorm = Loglike[1],
                    norm = Loglike[2],
                    weibul = Loglike[3],
                    gamma = Loglike[4],
                    GEV = Loglike[5]))
  
}



#  Creating data set
TLT <- c(rep(0,32), rep(1,120), rep(2,10), rep(3,67), rep(4,14),  rep(5,7), 6)
DLT_Code <- c(rep('DLT_Code',251))

data_to_plot <- data.frame(cbind(DLT_Code,TLT))
data_to_plot$TLT <- as.numeric(as.character(data_to_plot$TLT ))


DLT_Distr <- do.call(rbind, by(data = data_to_plot, INDICES = data_to_plot$DLT_Code, FUN=fdistr))
```

I was trying to play with `max_y` and then to use it in `ylim`. I could do it only for normal density, but not for the rest curves.

Currently plot looks like this (some curves are cut):

[image]

If to set up  `ylim =  c(0,2)` we can see, that lognormal and gamma distribution goes beyond 1:

[image]

I need to know the max value for each curve, so, when I choose which curve will be printed, to set up the correct `ylim`.

Comment: Finally I have used this solution, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56639782/find-the-maximum-of-the-function-in-r):   

`mygamma <- function(x) dgamma(x, shape=fit[['gamma']]$estimate[1],
                                    rate=fit[['gamma']]$estimate[2])  

 get_curve_values <- function(fn, x_data){ res <- curve(fn, from=0, to=x_data) dev.off() res }  
 curve_val <- get_curve_values(mygamma, x_data)  
 ylim <- max(curve_val$y,na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `purrr::map_dbl` to map the function `optimize` over your densities if you rearrange your code slightly and you have an idea over what input values you want to find their maxima/the density exists.

You can set your densities with whatever your parameters are ahead of time, that way you can find their peak values using `optimize` and also pass them to the `curve` function.

As a small reproducible example:

```
library(purrr)

# parameterize your densities
mynorm <- function(x) dnorm(x, mean = 0, sd = 1) 
mygamma <- function(x) dgamma(x, rate = .5, shape = 1) 

# get largest maximum over interval
ymax <- max(purrr::map_dbl(c(mynorm, mygamma), ~ optimize(., interval = c(0, 3), maximum = T)$objective))

# 0.4999811

# plot data
curve(mynorm, col = "blue", lwd = 2, xlim = c(0, 3), ylim = c(0, ymax * 1.1))
curve(mygamma, col = "red", lwd = 2, add = T)
```

---

Using your code I've implemented the above solution and adjusted the `x` grid of the `curve` function to show you what I mean after our discussion in the comments to make things more clear and show you what you should actually be plotting:

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(fitdistrplus)
library(evd)
library(gamlss)
library(purrr) # <- add this library


fdistr <- function(d) {
  
  #  Uncomment to try  run line by line
  # d <- data_to_plot
  
  TLT <- d$TLT
  if (sum(TLT<=0)) {TLT[TLT<=0] <- 0.001} # removing value < 0 for log clculation
  gev <- fgev(TLT, std.err=FALSE)
  distr <- c('norm', 'lnorm', 'weibull', 'gamma')
  fit <- lapply(X=distr, FUN=fitdist, data=TLT)
  fit[[5]] <- gev
  distr[5] <- 'gev'
  names(fit) <- distr
  Loglike <- sapply(X=fit, FUN=logLik)
  Loglike_Best <- which(Loglike == max(Loglike))
  
  #  Uncomment to try  run line by line
  # max <- which.max(density(d$TLT)$y)
  # max_density <- stats::density(d$TLT)$y[max]
  # max_y <- max_density
  
  x_data <- max(d$TLT)
  
  # parameterize your densities before plotting
  mynorm <- function(x) {
    dnorm(x, 
          mean=fit[['norm']]$estimate[1], 
          sd=fit[['norm']]$estimate[2])
  }
  
  mylnorm <- function(x){
    dlnorm(x, 
           meanlog=fit[['lnorm']]$estimate[1], 
           sdlog=fit[['lnorm']]$estimate[2])
  }
  
  myweibull <- function(x) {
    dweibull(x, 
             shape=fit[['weibull']]$estimate[1], 
             scale=fit[['weibull']]$estimate[2])
  }
  
  mygamma <- function(x) {
    dgamma(x, 
           shape=fit[['gamma']]$estimate[1], 
           rate=fit[['gamma']]$estimate[2])
  }
  
  mygev <- function(x){
    dgev(x, 
         loc=fit[['gev']]$estimate[1],
         scale=fit[['gev']]$estimate[2], 
         shape=fit[['gev']]$estimate[3])
  }
  
  distributions <- c(mynorm, mylnorm, myweibull, mygamma, mygev)
  
  # get the max of each density
  y <- purrr::map_dbl(distributions, ~ optimize(., interval = c(0, x_data), maximum = T)$objective)

  # find the max (excluding infinity)
  ymax <- max(y[abs(y) < Inf])
  
  
  hist(TLT, prob=TRUE, breaks= x_data,
       main=paste(d$DLT_Code[1], 
                  '- best :',
                  names(Loglike[Loglike_Best])),
       sub = 'Total Lead Times',
       col='lightgrey',
       border='white',
       ylim=  c(0, ymax)
  )
  
  lines(density(TLT),
        col='darkgrey',
        lty=2,
        lwd=2)
  
  grid(nx = NA, ny = NULL, col = "gray", lty = "dotted",
       lwd = .5, equilogs = TRUE)
  
  curve(mynorm, 
        add=TRUE, col='blue', lwd=2, n = 1E5) # <- increase x grid
  
  curve(mylnorm, 
        add=TRUE, col='darkgreen', lwd=2, n = 1E5) # <- increase x grid
  
  curve(myweibull, 
        add=TRUE, col='purple', lwd=2, n = 1E5) # <- increase x grid
  
  curve(mygamma, 
        add=TRUE, col='Gold', lwd=2, n = 1E5) # <- increase x grid
  
  
  curve(mygev, 
        add=TRUE, col='red', lwd=2, n = 1E5) # <- increase x grid
  
  
  legend_loglik <- paste(c('Norm', 'LogNorm', 'Weibull', 'Gamma','GEV'), c(':'),
                         round(Loglike, digits=2))
  
  legend("topright", legend=legend_loglik, 
         col=c('blue', 'darkgreen', 'purple', 'gold', 'red'),
         lty=1, lwd=2,
         bty='o', bg='white', box.lty=2, box.lwd = 1, box.col='white')  
  
  return(data.frame(DLT_Code = d$DLT_Code[1],
                    n = length(d$TLT),
                    Best = names(Loglike[Loglike_Best]),
                    lnorm = Loglike[1],
                    norm = Loglike[2],
                    weibul = Loglike[3],
                    gamma = Loglike[4],
                    GEV = Loglike[5]))
  
}



#  Creating data set
TLT <- c(rep(0,32), rep(1,120), rep(2,10), rep(3,67), rep(4,14),  rep(5,7), 6)
DLT_Code <- c(rep('DLT_Code',251))

data_to_plot <- data.frame(cbind(DLT_Code,TLT))
data_to_plot$TLT <- as.numeric(as.character(data_to_plot$TLT ))


DLT_Distr <- do.call(rbind, by(data = data_to_plot, INDICES = data_to_plot$DLT_Code, FUN=fdistr))
```

[image]

---

**Why your plot height isn't matching the solution output**

To illustrate further what's going on with your plot and some of the confusion you might have you need to understand how the `curve` function is plotting your data. By default `curve` takes 101 x-values and evaluates your functions to get their y-values and then plots those points as a line. Because the peaks on some of your density are so sharp, the `curve` function isn't evaluating enough x-values to plot your density peaks. To show you want I mean I will focus on your gamma density. Don't worry too much about the code as much as the output. Below I have the first few (x,y) coordinates for different values of `n`.

```
library(purrr)

mygamma <- function(x) {
  dgamma(x, 
         shape=fit[['gamma']]$estimate[1], # 0.6225622
         rate=fit[['gamma']]$estimate[2]) # 0.3568242
}

number_of_x <- c(5, 10, 101, 75000)
purrr::imap_dfr(number_of_x, ~ curve(mygamma, xlim = c(0, 6), n = .), .id = "n") %>% 
  dplyr::mutate_at(1, ~ sprintf("n = %i", number_of_x[as.numeric(.)])) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(n = factor(n, unique(n))) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(x > 0) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(n) %>% 
  dplyr::slice_min(order_by = x, n = 5)

 n                 x       y
   <fct>         <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 n = 5     1.5        0.184 
 2 n = 5     3          0.0828
 3 n = 5     4.5        0.0416
 4 n = 5     6          0.0219
 5 n = 10    0.667      0.336 
 6 n = 10    1.33       0.204 
 7 n = 10    2          0.138 
 8 n = 10    2.67       0.0975
 9 n = 10    3.33       0.0707
10 n = 101   0.06       1.04  
11 n = 101   0.12       0.780 
12 n = 101   0.18       0.655 
13 n = 101   0.24       0.575 
14 n = 101   0.3        0.518 
15 n = 75000 0.0000800 12.9   
16 n = 75000 0.000160   9.90  
17 n = 75000 0.000240   8.50  
18 n = 75000 0.000320   7.62  
19 n = 75000 0.000400   7.01
```

Notice that when `n = 5` you have very few values plotted. As `n` increases, the distance between the x-values gets smaller. Since these functions are continuous, there are infinite number of points to plot, but that cannot be done computationally so a subset of x-values are plotted to approximate. The more x-values the better the approximation. Normally, the default `n = 101` works fine, but because the gamma and log-normal densities have such sharp peaks the plot function is stepping over the maximum value. Below is a full plot of the data for `n = 5, 10, 101, 75000` with points added.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Hello @LMc,
your solution looks interesting, but does not work for all the cases>

I prefer to test it with my data - so I modified coed as per your example and `ymax` was 13, when it should not be higher than 2 (as on the second image in the question)
I have checked value for each function separately: 

```
ymax <- optimize(mydlnorm,  interval = c(0, x_data), maximum = T)$objective 

```
and almost for all functions for this dataset value is to high (I tried with another data and magically for another dataset it worked well).

Comment: I also tried to use `$max` argument, but did not work as well:

```
ymax <- optimize(mydgev,  interval = c(0, x_data), maximum = T)$max
```
This is modified code to try:
```
mynorm <- function(x) dnorm(x, 
                            mean=fit[['norm']]$estimate[1], 
                            sd=fit[['norm']]$estimate[2])

mydlnorm <- function(x) dlnorm(x, 
                               meanlog=fit[['lnorm']]$estimate[1], 
                               sdlog=fit[['lnorm']]$estimate[2])

```

Comment: ```
mydweibull <- function(x) dweibull(x, 
                                   shape=fit[['weibull']]$estimate[1], 
                                   scale=fit[['weibull']]$estimate[2])

mygamma <- function(x) dgamma(x, 
                              shape=fit[['gamma']]$estimate[1], 
                              rate=fit[['gamma']]$estimate[2])

mydgev <- function(x) dgev(x, 
                           loc=fit[['gev']]$estimate[1],
                           scale=fit[['gev']]$estimate[2], 
                           shape=fit[['gev']]$estimate[3])
 ```

Comment: #  Checking ymax for each function separately
# ymax <- optimize(mydlnorm,  interval = c(0, x_data), maximum = T)$objective
ymax <- max(purrr::map_dbl(c(mynorm, mydlnorm, mydweibull, mygamma, mydgev), ~ optimize(., interval = c(0, 3), maximum = T)$objective))
```

Comment: Sorry, I don´t know why it is not formatted as a code in the comment.

Comment: In comments you can use single backticks instead of sets of three to format. Which case did this not work for? And what was the error?

Comment: Regarding,  single backticks, I tried it in my comment to the question itself, it looks weird anyway.
It is not formatted line by line.Regarding the solution. 
There is no error, it would calculate something, the issue with the values I am getting.
To test it, you need to generate dataset, I have created in the question at the end and then run this code:

Comment: `TLT <- d$TLT
  if (sum(TLT<=0)) {TLT[TLT<=0] <- 0.001} # removing value < 0 for log clculation
  gev <- fgev(TLT, std.err=FALSE)
  distr <- c('norm', 'lnorm', 'weibull', 'gamma')
  fit <- lapply(X=distr, FUN=fitdist, data=TLT)
  fit[[5]] <- gev
  distr[5] <- 'gev'
  names(fit) <- distr
  Loglike <- sapply(X=fit, FUN=logLik)
  Loglike_Best <- which(Loglike == max(Loglike))

  mygamma <- function(x) dgamma(x, shape=fit[['gamma']]$estimate[1], rate=fit[['gamma']]$estimate[2])
ymax <- optimize(mygamma, interval = c(0, x_data), maximum = T)$objective`

Comment: The value `ymax` will be 13, it is to high, should be around 1. I have also posted the solution, which worked for me in the comment to the question.

Comment: Try plotting: `curve(dlnorm(x, -0.43, 2.5), ylim = c(0, 6))`. The hardcoded values are approximately what you have in your code above.

Comment: The shape is similar, but y axis values not. The highest green plot does not go over 2 with my data. And the idea is to find the highest point to adjust ylim for different data.

Comment: What I was trying to point out was using your code and data: `dlnorm(0.001, meanlog=fit[['lnorm']]$estimate[1], sdlog=fit[['lnorm']]$estimate[2])`. The height of this density at a value of `0.001` is over 6.

Comment: The issue with your posted answer and original question is that the `x` grid that is being searched in `curve`  is too coarse and actually misses the true max, which is why your plot appears to have heights around 1. When you use the `curve` function add the argument `n = 10000` for a finer grid and you will see your density plot above isn't capturing your true underlying densities. As I showed in the comment above your log-normal has a maximum density height of over 6, but appears to peak around 1.5 in your original question. So `optimize` is not returning incorrect values.

Comment: As I m not very proficient with statistics, I might miss some points here. Could you tell how did you get that plot with gamma curve till 15? I tried  to add `n= 1000` to all curve functions and only green curve `dlnorm` raised till 6, but all the rest including yellow (gamma) are below 4. Optimize function calculates max for dgamma = 15, but it did not plot till 15. Another interesting thing is your comment about  "`x `grid that is being searched in `curve ` is too coarse and actually misses the true max". What does it mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: If it is about this part `(sum(TLT<=0)) {TLT[TLT<=0] <- 0.001}` - initially it was `0` instead of `0.001`, but it did not work for some distribution functions, that is why I have replaced `0` to `0.001`.

Comment: My final goal is to find the best density curve for the data, that is why I am using this function, but I have already noticed that for some datasets I have weird results. Like this one or just a line, instead of typical density curve, so maybe I am using wrong parameters, but I don`t know which ones. Or maybe there are better ways to find the best distribution function for the data.

Comment: When you plot your gamma function raise the value of `n` to be even higher. In my code I used `n = 1E5`. `n` changes the number of values at which your function is evaluated. The more values you evaluate is known as a finer grid search. The less x values the more "coarse" your search. This `curve` function work by selecting (by default) 100 x values. Within your plot range of 0 to 6 this is enough x values to plot your true density height. The sequence of x-values steps right over the peaks for your log-normal and gamma. I will add additional information to my answer to help.

Comment: You had to use `(sum(TLT<=0)) {TLT[TLT<=0] <- 0.001}` because the gamma has support over positive values only. The gamma density is not defined at 0.

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed explanation! I understand it better, very helpful.  Now when I finally managed to plot properly ylim, I am wondering, why my distribution curve does not look like distribution (bell shape). Supposedly, function `fitdist`  helps to select the best fit. But can you say, that for that data, gamma model distribution is really the best fit and the curve is proper? Why it is so high? Are there better ways to find fitting distribution?

Comment: My suggestion would be to post that question as a new SO question since it's different than your original post. You might want to also include in that post some background on your variable.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have used this solution, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56639782/find-the-maximum-of-the-function-in-r):

```
mygamma <- function(x) dgamma(x, shape=fit[['gamma']]$estimate[1], 
                                  rate=fit[['gamma']]$estimate[2]) 
get_curve_values <- function(fn, x_data){
res <- curve(fn, from=0, to=x_data)
dev.off()
res
}
curve_val <- get_curve_values(mygamma, x_data)
ylim <- max(curve_val$y,na.rm = TRUE)
```